# In Haxe, how to create an object of template class T and assign properties to it

Tags: haxe

I want to do these in a util class for all classes which have position and size

```
class Creator<T> {

   public function create() {
       …
       var object = new T(); // compile error: T is a compile time class or something (?)
       object.x = x_; // compile error: T doesn't have an x properties
       …
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read the [Haxe manual](http://haxe.org/manual). The part you are interested on is how Haxe manages the Type parameters [here](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameters.html) and how to apply Constraints to them [here](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-type-parameter-constraints.html). Once you have read that, the way you can achieve it is similar to [this.](http://try.haxe.org/#7378c)

Comment: How do I create constrant typedef for any type that has `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` without specific getters and setters or type since the properties `width` and `height` could be sometimes `Float` or `Int`?

Comment: @DleanJeans There is no way you could do that. Getters/setters are part of field description. Also, regarding Float/Int, you could do that in general, but just guessing what you want to achieve in the end, there is no way you could make it useful for you, because the amount of templating will be obscene for all of your classes which use this thing.

Comment: @DleanJeans while possible, I don't recommend it. You will need to use `Reflect` and `Type` to create and modify fields. [Here](http://try.haxe.org/#B2f80) is the last example modified. This method will be always slower and, probably, prone to errors with different targets.